# picker view array row is will only display 0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int, pickerview

I have a picker view of int in my Swift code. It has numbers 1-7 in an array called numbers. When I ask to print `numbers[row]` inside the `didSelectRow` function it prints the correct numbers. But within my submit tapped function it only prints 0. It did this in `viewWillAppear` as well.

I essentially want the row to be a variable that I can use as an int to delay some code.

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var days = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(days)
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return String(numbers[row])
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var days = numbers[row]
    print(days)
}

@IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    databaseRef.child("numbers").child(self.TextField.text!).setValue(["thename" : UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "nametext")])
    print(days)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(days) , execute: {
        databaseRef.child("numbers/\(self.TextField.text!)").removeValue()
    })
```

Does anyone know why it is always returning zero in the submit tapped function?

Comment: these solutions work I simply deleted var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing `days` using the `Int()` constructor, which is always `0`. Thus, in your `viewWillAppear(_:)` method later, `0` is printed out, because that's what `days` was initialized to be. However, in your `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` method, you're using the `var` keyword to *create a new variable called `days`* that is *local to the `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` method*, and the global `days` variable is never changed, and is always equal to `0`. Therefore, later on in your `submitTapped(_:)` method, the global `days` is still `0`.

I'm going to assume you want to set the global `days` variable in your `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` method to `numbers[row]`. To do so, you must remove the `var` keyword next to `days` inside the `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)`. Inside that method, you can reference it either as `days` or `self.days`, as long as you don't use the `var` or `let` keyword to redeclare `days` inside that method

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    var days = numbers[row]
    print(days)
```

with

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    days = numbers[row]
    print(days)
```

Your code doesn't work because you are creating new variable and you are not referencing your instance variable.